# Solve $x''(t) x(t)=x^4(t)$ with $x'(0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2},x(0)=0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the Cauchy problem:
$$x''(t) x(t)=x^4(t)$$
with $x'(0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2},x(0)=0$.

I would appreciate some help with this problem.

Thank you very much.

EDIT. My approach:

$$x(t)\left(x''(t) -x^3(t)\right)=0 \Rightarrow x(t)=0, \ \ x''(t)=x^3(t)$$

whence

$$x'(t)x''(t)=x^3(t)x'(t)$$

and so on.

Comment: Start with a substitution $x'(t)=u(x)$. Convince yourself that $x''(t)=u'(x)u(x)$. Integrate.

Comment: what do you mean with $x^4(t)$?

Comment: Why do you have x(t) on both sides?

Comment: @martycohen This equation is a priori weaker than $x''=x^3$, since it is automatically satisfied at the initial point (i.e. $x''(0)$ is not determined).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution can be written as

$$ x(t) = \left( 1/2+i/2 \right) \sqrt {2}\; {sc} \left(  \left( 1/2-i/2
 \right) t \mid \sqrt {2} \right) 
$$

where $sc$ is a [Jacobi elliptic function](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=JacobiAM).

Answer (score 0):

$$
x'' = x^3
$$
Mutiple by $x'$ leads to
$$
x''x' = x^3x'\implies \frac{1}{2}\left(x'^2\right)' =\left(\frac{x^4}{4}\right)'
$$
can you solve?
Integrating once and Using the initial conditions at $t=0$
We find that
$$
\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2} = \frac{(0)^4}{4} + C
$$
Thus we find (edit thanks to winther)
$$
x' =\pm\frac{\sqrt{x^4+1}}{\sqrt{2}}
$$

Comment: It should be $x' = \sqrt{x^4 + 1}/\sqrt{2}$

Comment: I am pretty sure I am correct as the integration constant is 1/4 thus pulled out is 1/2? Though I will check again :). Cheers

Comment: Actually I see what you mean now..sorry for dragging this out!!